# No output in console.log. Beginner Question

Tags: javascript, printing, console.log

I'm reading Head 1st JavaScript book and try to learn the language as much as i can. Wanted to to all the problems from the book. After i did so for one of the problems, and wrote the code as i thought, and checked the solution, i changed it to reflect the solution in the book even thou it worked for me. The thing is, when i want to "print" in the console now, nothing shows up and idk why... i don't see nor have a problem...
Any idea why the console.log will not output anything? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        function Coffee(roast, ounces) {
            this.roast = roast;
            this.ounces = ounces;
            this.getSize = function() {
            if (this.ounces === 8) {
                return "small";
            } else if (this.ounces === 12) {
                return "medium";
            } else (this.ounces === 16); {
                return "large";
            }
        };
            this.toString = function() {
                return "You have ordered a " + this.getSize() + " " + this.roast + " coffee.";
            };
        }
        var csmall = new Coffee ("House Blend",  "8");
        var cmedium = new Coffee ("House Blend", "12");
        var clarge = new Coffee ("Dark Roast", "16");
        var coffees = [csmall, cmedium, clarge];

        for (var i = 0; i < coffees.length; i++) {
            coffees[i].toString();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This is the way i wrote the code and worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        function Coffee(roast, size, ounces) {
            this.roast = roast;
            this.size = size;
            this.ounces = ounces;
            this.getSize = function() {
            if (this.ounces === 8) {
                console.log("You have ordered a " + this.size + " " + this.roast + " coffee.");
            } else if (this.ounces === 12) {
                console.log("You have ordered a " + this.size + " " + this.roast + " coffee.");
            } else (this.ounces === 16); {
                console.log("You have ordered a " + this.size + " " + this.roast + " coffee.");
            }
            };
        }
        var csmall = new Coffee ("House Blend", "small",  "8");
        var cmedium = new Coffee ("House Blend", "medium", "12");
        var clarge = new Coffee ("Dark Roast", "large", "16");
        var coffees = [csmall, cmedium, clarge];

        for (var i = 0; i < coffees.length; i++) {
            coffees[i].getSize();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the fiurst code, you never call `console.log()` therefore it never logs to the console.

Comment: Interesting idea with the `toString`, however, this function is not usually intended to be called explicitly. It gets automatically called when the value is coerced to a string, e.g. `document.body.textContent = coffees[i];`. But the real issue here is the lack of `console.log`. In the `for` loop, use `console.log(String(coffees[i]));`.

Answer (score 0):

In above code console log has not been used so this is why you haven't seen any thing in the console

```
for (var i = 0; i < coffees.length; i++) {
        coffees[i].toString();
        console.log(String(coffees[i])); // <-- add here
    }
```

Still it would give incorrect result becuase it used === in the function which means the type of the value supplied will also match with type in the function

It used integers in function but supplied value in string see the code below

```
if (this.ounces === 8) { // used === to match type as well here it is integer
            return "small";
        } else if (this.ounces === 12) {
            return "medium";
        } else (this.ounces === 16); {
            return "large";
        }
    };
        this.toString = function() {
            return "You have ordered a " + this.getSize() + " " + this.roast + " coffee.";
        };
    }
    var csmall = new Coffee ("House Blend",  "8"); // passing it as string "8" it should be just 8
    var cmedium = new Coffee ("House Blend", "12");
    var clarge = new Coffee ("Dark Roast", "16");
```

Correct Code should be like this

```
<script>
    function Coffee(roast, ounces) {
        this.roast = roast;
        this.ounces = ounces;
        this.getSize = function() {
        if (this.ounces === 8) {
            return "small";
        } else if (this.ounces === 12) {
            return "medium";
        } else (this.ounces === 16); {
            return "large";
        }
    };
        this.toString = function() {
            return "You have ordered a " + this.getSize() + " " + this.roast + " coffee.";
        };
    }
    var csmall = new Coffee ("House Blend",  8);
    var cmedium = new Coffee ("House Blend", 12);
    var clarge = new Coffee ("Dark Roast", 16);
    var coffees = [csmall, cmedium, clarge];

    for (var i = 0; i < coffees.length; i++) {
        coffees[i].toString();
        console.log(String(coffees[i]));
    }
</script>
```

But in the secon code which is done by you...

I beleive the real problem was to use logic and convert ounces into size by getsize function where as you directly used sizes in your solution